# What is an alternative for "thank you"?

Tags: synonyms

So...

I am seeking a new job and several recruiters are helping me. Instead of saying 'Thank you', should I say 'I appreciate'? Which one is more polite?

Could someone please tell me how to express one's gratefulness to someone else in English?

Comment: Thank you.  Thanks.  I really appreciate your help.  This really helps.  Thank you _so_ much.  (...)

Comment: *"I am honored."*

Comment: "Thank you" is a full sentence, "I appreciate" is not. "I appreciate your help" is ok. And FYI: The word is "gratitude", not "gratefulness".

Comment: Valar morghulis

Answer (score 22):

"Thank you" is serviceable in all contexts. Since it is so common, though, it may not feel like enough. In that case, you can say "I appreciate your help" or "Thank you so much" or "I'm very grateful" — there are many ways to express gratitude.

Nevertheless, remind yourself that recruiters *are* getting paid for their work, so you shouldn't feel you have to be too effusive in your thanks. A simple "thank you" will probably suffice.

Answer (score 10):

The best one is:

> I am honored.

Longer ones describing what you are honored by are even better:

> I am honored to be graced by your
>   presence.

It reminds me of Tolkien and Paolini. :)

---

If you don't like being a hobbit, there's always "Thanks", which makes everyone but elves comfortable.

(Sauron doesn't like being thanked either.)

Comment: "I am honored..." doesn't fit the example case at all.  (It would probably work if the recruiters were elves and you were a hobbit.)

Comment: I fail to see why this reply has received so many upvotes. When applying for a job, “I am honoured to be graced by your presence” is a ***completely wrong*** thing to say to a recruiter helping you. You would be considered positively delusional if you went around saying such things.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Robusto's answer, which I agree with *almost* completely, note that there may be regional differences in how effusive (or not) you might want to be with recruiters.  It is their job, and you probably don't want to sound puppy-dog-like in your enthusiasm, but it is often generically expected to provide at least pro forma thanks (which may at least bias the recruiter towards suggesting some of the better bad jobs to you).

Definitely use at least "I appreciate it," instead of just "I appreciate" .

A few variations on "thanks", from most enthusiastic to least:

- Thanks!
- Thanks,
  [your familiar name, or first name, nickname, etc.]
- Thanks,
  [your full name]

Some other variations I consider appropriate and acceptable:

- Thanks for your efforts
- Thanks for your help
- Thanks for you time
- Thanks for your assistance

Less formal:

- Appreciate [it, your help, your time, etc.]
- Thanks, [recruiter's name]

Compound endings.

- That's great. Thanks.
- Sounds great, thanks.

Special use, for when you've already used "thanks" six times:

- Always appreciated, [your name]

or more familiar,

- Always appreciated, [recruiter's name]

The "it" or "your help" is implied here, though you could also explicitly add it.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use *obliged* in these types of situations, although *thank you* really is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use *thank you kindly* a lot.

Comment: But what does it mean? Are you being kind to the recipient by expressing your gratitude?

Comment: @ADTC *Kindly* here is an adverb: I'm thanking someone in a kind and warmhearted manner. It's more than a simple obligation, to me it sounds more appreciative.

Comment: I actually don't understand what you said. "In a kind (snip) manner", meaning you are being kind to the recipient by thanking them? In any case, it sounds odd. Especially since *kindly* is normally used as a slightly more formal substitute for *please*, to mean you are hoping that the recipient shows kindness to you by performing the requested task. On a side note, could you actually be meaning to say *thank you in kind* (where *kind* means sameness or reciprocity)?

Comment: @ADTC Perhaps [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55771/whats-the-deal-with-thank-you-kindly) will help. FumbleFingers correctly notes that the usage of *kindly* in the phrase is a bit archaic, meaning "with goodwill and enthusiasm; very much."It does not mean *thank you in kind*, and it does not mean that I am pointing out that I am being kind in my thanks. It is simply an intensifier. It is equivalent to saying *thank you very much.*

Answer (score 1):

In Romanian, "thank you" is: "mulţumesc", the literal translation of which is simply: "I'm happy".

So I guess "I appreciate" is another way of expressing that you are happy.

"I appreciate..." is in my opinion more elegant than "I'm grateful" because "grateful" is closer to "I'm indebted".

However, I'd also consider "I enjoyed..."

I would rank things like this

1. "I enjoyed..." which conveys a sense
   community of thought and possibly a
   convergence of interest.
2. "I appreciate..." which is a less strong but could be misinterpreted as a "refusal" (as in "I appreciate the effort but...").  Consider that this phrasing is probably what you would use for instance if the offered opportunity came only as a second choice for you.
3. "I'm grateful..." could sound like as "I didn't think I could make it !".
4. "I'm indebted...".  Use this and they will slash half of your wages off.

That's my 2cts of course.  I any case you've probably finished that letter by now ;-).

Comment: Hi! About your first line; could you clarify how "mulţumesc" means "I'm happy"? I am Romanian, and the only ways I can think of to say "I'm happy" are "sunt bucuros" or "sunt fericit". The only thing close to "mulţumesc" that I can think of is ""mulţumit", but I would rather translate that as "satisfied".

Comment: Fine "I'm satisfied". Big difference.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I personally prefer to use " I would really appreciate your kind assistance" or "I would like to express my deepest gratitude for your kind assistance".

I think it is more formal to express your gratitude towards the person as "thank you" is a general statement which does not explain in details for what you owed him/ her a thank you.

Comment: Your first suggestion is not about expressing gratitude, it is in fact, *asking* for assistance, so quite the opposite. It should be: *"I really appreciated your kind assistance"*. Your second might be construed by native speakers for sarcasm. *"I'd like to express my gratitude for your help"* is more than enough! :) You should edit your answer.