# Why is it "serviceable" but not "servicable"?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, able-eable

I came across this word in the answer provided by [Robusto](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto) for the question about [Thank you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/what-is-alternative-for-thank-you).

Because the last *e* in *service* is not pronounced, I thought it should be deleted when *service* is appended by *able*.

I guess the reason for *serviceable* may be related to the fact that the *i* in *service* is pronounced as [ɪ] but not [aɪ].

However, I am not sure, and I would like to know the reason behind that.

Comment: One clue would be that "serviceable" shows up in the dictionary, whereas "servicable" does not.

Comment: @Robusto, I know. I had googled it before I asked this question. I just want to know the reason.

Comment: Relevant: *[Adjective form of collide — collideable or collidable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/adjective-form-of-collide-collideable-or-collidable)* and [the section on -able in Wikipedia's list of American and British English spelling differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Dropped_e). In particular, "Both forms of the language retain the silent *e* when it is necessary to preserve a soft *c,* *ch,* or *g,* such as in *traceable, cacheable, changeable"*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The c is pronounced like k except when it comes before i or e: then it is pronounced like s. In *service*, c comes before e, so that it is pronounced s. If we add -*able*, we should normally remove the e, as you said; but then we'd get *servicable*. Because c before a is pronounced k, the sound of the word would change profoundly; that is undesirable, which is why we add an extra e: serviceable. The same applies to g: *change => chang-able => changeable.*

Answer (score 9):

Because "servicable" would be pronounced with a hard c.

Comment: So what? So there's your answer, @Dante Jiang. And to @James McLeod, +1 from me.

Comment: I thought the same thing, pronounced it "Servik-able" when I tried to say Servicable.

Comment: @James McLeod, @Robusto, so, the reason is that if I suffix a word, I should not change the _original_ pronunciation?

Comment: In English, there are few absolute rules, but I can't think of any case where the "s" sound like at the end of "service" is changed into a "k" sound by a suffix.

Comment: @Dante Jiang: unfortunately, it's not as simple as that. When a suffix derived from Latin is added, it can change both vowel and consonant sounds ("urbane" <=> "urbanity"; "electric" <=> "electricity"). When a native English suffix is added (such as "-able") this is less likely to happen. Of course this is not a great deal of help for a foreign leaner of English.

Comment: @Colin: Well put (I assume that by "native" you mean "that is or was once productive in English": as we all know *-able* is derived from a Latin suffix too).

Comment: @Cerberus: good point. I'm not sure what I mean. "-able" feels English in a way that "-ity" doesn't, but as you say they're both from Latin. Perhaps it's that "-able" gets added to both Latin and English roots, but "-ity" hardly ever to English ones.

Comment: @Colin: That is a sound marker. The difference is that *-able* can be used, or was once used, in actual English to create new words, whereas *-ity* is felt to be a truly Latin suffix, i.e. you could not use it to create a new word in English. Because it is traditionally not used to create new words in English, you would not find it attached to Germanic roots. It is still felt to be truly Latin as a suffix, even though I believe some modern vogue words have in fact started to use it in English.