# Longest sentence yet (Text Analysis). How do we decompile this sentence?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, that

**> Context:
On the other hand, Italian writers did well to draw on the Tuscan vernacular rather than the other vernaculars of Italy [1250] for the reasons that everyone knows and which we have stated pp.1246, end-47, beginning.**

> But it would be silly, absurd, pedantic, and ridiculous to conclude from this **that** only **that** vernacular can therefore be drawn on, **that** writers can only write in the manner and to the extent **that that** particular people speaks, **that** the Italian language and Italian literature wholly depend on the common people of Tuscany (when it does not even depend on the common people at all, but simply uses them when it so chooses), **that** in and outside of Tuscany, an Italian writer cannot create words or phrases **that** the Tuscan populace does not use, **that**, in short, someone **who** is not Tuscan, indeed, **who** is not Florentine, or not actually from the Old Market, is not Italian.

The questions would be:

1.There are two **'that'** in line 3, would someone kindly explain this queer using of '**that'**?

2.Is it acceptable writing in English using 'that' so many times in a single sentence? Wouldn't it be more appropriate if for example the first and second line:
'But it would be silly, absurd, pedantic, and ridiculous to conclude that only vernacular can therefore be drawn on'

3.If we decompile those **'thats'** into multiple sentences, would it change the conveyed meaning?

Thank you!

Comment: Source: Zibaldone - Giacomo Leopardi (Italian writer, translated into English)

Comment: It's the standard use of two *thats*, that happens occasionally in English. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem). It's much less confusing in the spoken language, because the first is generally pronounced /ðət/ or /ðɪt/, while the second is pronounced /ðæt/.

Comment: @Peter Would you care to explain more of this standard use of two thats?

Comment: You could rewrite the relevant clause as *that writers can only write in the manner in which, and to the extent to which, that particular people speaks*. Hopefully that helps. The first *that* replaces both *in which* and *to which*.

Comment: To answer your revised question, I think all the parallel *that*'s are fine (*that only*, *that writers*, *that the Italian language*, *that in and outside of Tuscany*, and *that, in short*). The non-parallel ones tend to confuse the reader, though, and it would be good to replace them where possible. For (2), a better rewrite would  be *"that only the Tuscan vernacular can therefore be drawn on"* (and I would agree that that is an improvement). The penultimate *that* could be replaced by *which*, and *that that* could be replaced by *that this*, leaving only one non-parallel *that*.

Comment: But the sentence, as originally written, is perfectly grammatical if somewhat confusing.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55873

Answer (score 1):

There are two uses of the word `that` in English.

> He went through the door that was open. She wanted that car.

This use is describing something. Which car? That car. Which door? The one that was open.

> She said that the car was marvelous. He wished that the door was spring-loaded.

This use is different. It is connected to the verb - I can "wish that I had something" or "promise that I will return" but not all verbs will work with it.

So

> to conclude from this that only that vernacular can therefore be drawn on

could be rewritten as " to conclude from this that only *the Tuscan* vernacular *of the time* can therefore be drawn on" as a way of replacing the second `that`, which is the "describing that". You can't replace the first `that` as easily, maybe replace "conclude that" with "draw a conclusion such as".

Most sentences with both uses of `that` in them should be rewritten to avoid it, in my opinion. Even native speakers sometimes have to back up and read them again. Your sentence is really quite difficult to read and gives a "show off" vibe that may not be intended, since it's a translation.